# Bazel: how to create genrule that uses cmd on linux and cmd_bat on windows?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'd like to make Bazel rules that don't depend on Bash on Windows.

I see that in a `genrule`, you can use cmd_bat instead of cmd (which requires bash). But how can I define the rule so that there is a cmd attribute and a cmd_bat attribute, and on Windows only cmd_bat is used and everywhere else cmd is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bazel 3.2.0 `cmd_bat` is only considered on Windows. In other operating systems it is simply ignored. `cmd_bat` has a higher priority than `cmd`.

Comment: does 'higher priority' mean that if there is a cmd_bat AND a cmd, that the cmd will be ignored?

Comment: great, thanks! I interpreted it as being always executed first